# Consolidating/rationalizing leak tags

Tags: discussion

We have a [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) that is primarily used for vehicle fluid leaks, as well as few fluid specific leak tags ([coolant-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coolant-leak) with 9 uses, [oil-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-leak) with 72 uses, and [atf-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atf-leak) which is currently unused) and [water-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-leak) for rain leaking into the car. I'm wondering if it would be better to have a single tag for mechanical leaks (as opposed to bodywork leaks) this qualified with the fluid in question. This would mean, for example that [oil-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-leak) would go away and be replaced by [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) and [oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil). Water leaks tagged as [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) would be moved to [water-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-leak).

I think this would simplify finding leaks and would stop a growing collection of kind-of-leak tags (and would save users from needing to know about them).

Answer (score 3):

### I'll give a few examples

... of tags I feel have hit the sweet spot between being too broad (and thus vague) and overly specific (so not very representative of the problem):

- [strange-sounds](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strange-sounds)

  - Example of "too broad": [noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise)
  - Example of "too specific": [squeaking](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/squeaking), [ticking](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticking) (don't exist on the site)
- [cranks-wont-run](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cranks-wont-run)

  - Example of "too broad": [no-start](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-start)
  - Example of "too specific": [starter-motor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starter-motor)
- [cold-start](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-start)

  - Example of "too broad": [starting](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starting), [stall](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stall)
  - Example of "too specific": [winter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter)

---

### My $0.02

- Since SE allows a maximum of 5 tags per question, I don't think separating [oil-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-leak) into [oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil) and [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) is adding much value.
- For oddball leaks, we could continue to maintain the [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) tag, but caveat its usage as such by highlighting that other tags exist for more specific leaks. So oil leaks, coolant leaks and transmission leaks would keep their tags, but refrigerant leaks and brake fluid leaks would use [leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leak) and another tag to make the problem more specific.
- The decision of whether to create a dedicated tag for a specific type of leak should be based on how often the issue recurs.

  So when flux capacitors finally make their presence felt in mainstream vehicles, if their propensity for leaking is deemed high enough, [flux-capacitor-leak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flux-capacitor-leak) earns its right to exist.

Comment: Shh, we're not supposed to be leaking the existence of flux capacitors in consumer vehicles yet!